# GeoPandas .to_file gives wrong column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, geopandas

I have a GeoDataFrame with a column of float values and I want to transform them in int values, then overwrite the shapefile.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

gdf=gpd.read_file(r'.\folder\gdf.shp')
```

This gdf has a column of float values, float_column:

```
gdf["float_column"]

0      1.307500e+12
1      1.307500e+12
2      1.307500e+12
3      1.307500e+12
4      1.307500e+12
5      1.307500e+12
6      1.307500e+12
7      1.307500e+12
8      1.307500e+12
9      1.307500e+12
```

Then I apply a transformation:

```
gdf["int_column"]=[int(x) for x in gdf["float_column"]]
```

Which has these values (right transformation):

```
gdf["int_column"]

0      1307500192816
1      1307500170116
2      1307500012418
3      1307500152317
4      1307500141816
5      1307500093417
6      1307500055117
7      1307500081117
8      1307500107717
9      1307500096916
10     1307500213815
```

Then I save the gdf:

```
gdf.to_file(r".\folder\gdf.shp",driver='ESRI Shapefile',crs_wkt=prj)
```

And when I cross-check the result int_column has these values:

```
gdf_try=gpd.read_file(r'.\folder\gdf.shp')

gdf_try["int_column"]

0      2147483647
1      2147483647
2      2147483647
3      2147483647
4      2147483647
5      2147483647
6      2147483647
7      2147483647
8      2147483647
9      2147483647
```

Which seems totally crazy! Did I miss something very stupid??

Comment: Not sure how geopandas works but `2147483647` is the maximum number an int32 holds, maybe you could try `long`? Or maybe checking your `gdf` dtypes can give a hint?

Comment: Tried with `int(x)`, `np.int32(x)`, `np.int64(x)`, `long(x)`, `np.long(x)`, nothing happens... checking the dtypes with `np.long(x)` that column is `int64`, but still full of `2147483647`

Comment: Guess the problem is in your `to_file` then. Again, not sure how it works, but id say this driver can handle int64s?

Comment: I thought this too. This is my question though!

Comment: Why cant you save as strings?

Comment: That's what I did actually. And it works. Just wondering about long ints...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is, as noted in the comments, due to `int32` limits. The proper dtype isn't being inferred, leading to the loss of information. This should be resolved with an upcoming release of `fiona` (which `geopandas` uses for reading/writing files), which will improve how `int` types are handled (https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/pull/564). In the meantime, you can use

```
schema = gpd.io.file.infer_schema(gdf)
schema['properties']['int_column'] = 'int:18'
gdf.to_file('gdf.shp', schema=schema)
```